How can I vent an uninsulated garage to reduce humidity?
My garage is about 20x18’ and 11’ tall. Walls and ceilings are unfinished. My entry door is opposite of my garage door and has a window that opens. During the winter we often arrive home from out snow on the car and when it melts in the garage it creates a lot of humidity. Some tools have rusted due to this. I’ll leave my entry door window open and crack the garage door to help, but would like to add vents so the garage door doesn’t need to be cracked.
I was thinking of adding roof vents like my attic has. Anyone have any thoughts if this will help with the winter humidity and heat in the summer? How many should I add? I thought about adding a powered vent but I only have one circuit in the garage and I am afraid it would get overloaded. Any thoughts are appreciated.


Vents may be a good idea, but we need more info.  Pics will help, and tell us if the garage is attached to the home or freestanding.   There are small sized power vents that pull a small amount of power, but we need more details before suggesting anything.

Roof vents—like a ridge vent?  If you have exhaust air, you would need some way to basically have "intake" air.  Are there gables?   Do you have a pic or sketch of the garage interior and exterior?

I am referring to static attic vents. There currently are no vents installed and the garage is not insulated. I currently need to leave the garage door cracked and the entry door open to help with ventilation. My thought is that I can leave the door window open with roof vents and not have both door wide open.

You could go with a powered roof vent (fan).  Or a gable mount fan on the top of one of the walls.  In either case you would need to provide a means for make up air to enter the garage.

Are you sure there's not something else going on here?  You didn't say where you're located, but in most part of the country (US) the humidity level is pretty low in the winter, with dew points below 30 deg F.  I would think that would dry out any moisture in the garage in short order, unless the building is really air tight.

@SteveSh, slop melting off a car every day won't dry out in short order, especially at just above freezing. We're talking about gallons.

@isherwood - I never had a high relative humidity problem in a unheated garage in a vacation home I owned for a while in the mountains of West Virginia, at least that I know of.  When I up there during snow events, I always cleared as much snow off the car or truck as I could reasonably do before driving or putting it in the garage.  It never went into the garage with 4" or 6" or 8" of snow on it.

It's not about the snow on it. You can have 30 lbs. packed into the wheel wells and undercarriage (at least here, where we have real winter :P ). There's so much that I recently cut drains into my garage floor.

Ridge venting or a series of common static vents will help in all seasons. Your garage isn't so airtight that you'd need to keep things open down low. A small household fan circulating during wet periods would also help.
Ridge vent can be easily cut in with a circular saw and demolition blade (read: an old carbide blade). You'll have to replace your ridge cap shingles, though.
Common static vents can be cut in easily as well. You'll just need to pull a few shingle nails above the hole to slide the flange under for proper drainage. I would install four or five vents for your building size. Place them just below the ridge on the least conspicuous side.
